# Outputing PHP to JavaScript function

Tags: php, javascript, html, prototype

I'm having problems outputting php to javascript when i only output one line javascript works when i put my for loop in javascript breaks no errors just no output i use firebug and i see that output is bugged for instance:

"'ANS" . '+' . "'ANS". '+' . "'ANS" If i output text like this from php it works. When i output a single anchor like so:

```
'"' . '<a href="#">Text</a>' . '"';
```

However when i put this in a for loop it breaks i tried many options:

```
function step1() {
            modalbox.show(new Element("div").insert(
                new Element("p", { "align": "justify" }).insert(
                    <?php $i = 0; ?>
                    <?php foreach ($items as $category => $itemsattr): $i++; ?>
                        <?php if($i == 27): ?>
                            <?= "'" . '<a class="category" href="#"> '. $category . '</a>' . "'" ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                            <?= "'" . '<a class="category" href="#"> '. $category . '</a>' . "'+" ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                )
            ), {
                "title"     : "Step 1/3",
                "width"     : 800,
                "options"   : [{
                    "label"     : "Next »",
                    "onClick"   : step2
                }]
            });
        };
```

If i output only one like this it works:

```
<?= "'" . '<a class="category" href="#">Text</a>' . "'" ?>
```

However when i put that in a loop and add '+ at the end of each one except last one it breaks.

My for loop outputs this when checked with Firebug:

```
'<a class="category" href="#"> Assault Ship</a>'+ '<a class="category" href="#"> Battlecruiser</a>'
```

From what i know this should be valid for javascript is there another way more secure for outputing php past javascript to avoid problems like this ?

Comment: Why are we looking at PHP rather than what outputs in the HTML where the problem should be a lot more obvious? Also, 'ew' at server side code building client-side code. This has not been a historically awesome approach. Better to write static JS to handle a JSON object handed down from the server side.

Comment: what is this `<?php if($i == 27): ?>` for? no + sign there. end of the cycle? And look what is JS error Firebug reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
<?php foreach ($items as $category => $itemsattr): $i++; ?>
    <?php if($i == 27): ?>
        <?= "'" . '<a class="category" href="#"> '. $category . '</a>' . "'" ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <?= "'" . '<a class="category" href="#"> '. $category . '</a>' . "'+" ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

What if you try something like this?

```
<?php echo "'"; ?>
<?php foreach ($items as $category => $itemsattr): $i++; ?>
    <?php if($i == 27): ?>
        <?= '<a class="category" href="#"> '. $category . '</a>' ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <?= '<a class="category" href="#"> '. $category . '</a>' ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php echo "'"; ?>
```

You also may have better luck with this; it's more scalable than what you had:

```
<?php foreach ($items as $category => $itemsattr): $i++; ?>
    <?php if($i == 0): ?>
        <?= "'" . '<a class="category" href="#"> '. $category . '</a>' . "'" ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?= "+'" . '<a class="category" href="#"> '. $category . '</a>' . "'" ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Note the different placement of the + as well as the first conditional.

Like others have said, this general approach may not be the best, but this might make what you have work better...